# Xamarin ListView: difference between constructor and emulator

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, height

I've the following grid layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:rowCount="5">
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_rowWeight="0.7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Введите показания водомера"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="0.05"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <EditText
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_rowWeight="0.03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:text="Сделать фото"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="0.05"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <Button
        android:text="Отправить показания"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="0.15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />
</GridLayout>
```

In the Vs constructor it look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWPE8.png).
But in the emulator I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyuYm.png).
How can I set a height of ListView like on the 1st image?

Comment: Is there particular reason why you use `GridLayout`? With hardcoded `width` and `height` you will hard achieve what you want. Why not using `LinearLayout` as a container with vertical orientation and inside 2 `LinearLayouts` with weights of 2 and 1. I one you will put `ListView` in second rest of the code.

Comment: @Yupi `GridLayout` allow me to resize controls on the differenct devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix this by adding a custom android.support.v7 from nuget to my project and using its schema in xml.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:columnCount="1"
    app:rowCount="5">
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```